# Maintaining js while appending elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not super experienced and was hoping someone could give me some tips.

I'm trying to create a system where images can be transferred from a holding container to a manipulative container where they can be re-sized and dragged.

I have a manipulative here: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/jxY8M/98/)

And am trying to get the "click in/double-click out" system to work here: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/jxY8M/102/)

```
<div class="frame"></div>

<div class="inventory">
     <images>
</div>


$(".frame img")
    .draggable({
     containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move"
}).resizable({
    aspectRatio:1,
    containment: "parent",
    minHeight: 50,
    minWidth: 50
});


$('.inventory img').click(function(){ 
   $(this).appendTo(".frame");
 });
$('.frame img').dblclick(function(){
   $(this).appendTo(".inventory");
   $(this).removeClass('added');

});
```

The main problem I believe is that once I append the divs, the js doesn't refresh and apply based on the arrangements of elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Arun P Johny's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4xKW/2/.

```
$(".frame img")
    .draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move"
}).resizable({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    containment: "parent",
    minHeight: 50,
    minWidth: 50
});

$('.inventory').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $(this).resizable({
        aspectRatio: 1,
        containment: "parent",
        minHeight: 50,
        minWidth: 50
    });

    $(this).parent().appendTo(".frame").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        cursor: "move"
    });
});

$('.frame').on('dblclick', '.ui-draggable', function () {
    $(this).appendTo(".inventory");
    $(this).draggable("destroy");
    $("img", this).resizable("destroy");
});
```

This adds and removes the draggable and resizable functions from the items when they are added and removed.

Comment: Thank you! If it's not too much trouble, there are a couple more things I would like it to do. Looking here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/VuyS4/1/. I was hoping that when the images were dblclicked back to the yellow frame they would revert to the sizes dictated in .inventory img {}, take on a blocked position, and not overlap. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I would probably use [jQuery's .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to store the dimension of the object and retrieve/use them when I double click on the object.

Comment: Since you are not using inline styles, we could just remove the style attribute that is added by the resize and drag functions. Here is the updated fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/VuyS4/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/VuyS4/2/) Code change: .removeAttr("style")

Answer (score 2):

Since the evaluation of the selectors need to be dynamic you need to use event delegation

```
$('.inventory').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $(this).appendTo(".frame");
});
$('.frame').on('dblclick', 'img', function () {
    $(this).appendTo(".inventory");
    $(this).removeClass('added');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4xKW/)

Note: This will not handle the resizable/draggable behaviors - you will need to manually destroy/add this behaviors when you move the element from one container to another one

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Do you know how I could get them to be manipulable while their in .frame?

Comment: Similarly to the first link, I would like to be able to move and resize the images when they are under .frame.

Comment: Did that answer the question?